# How can I nest a table rows inside a table columns?

Tags: html

I am using a table to out put some data in a tabular format. (Below is just a small example of what I am really working with) I am trying to create a 2 column layout. Both columns will contain table rows.  But I am trying them to create both td as a container for the table rows.

This is how my code looks

```
    <table>

<tr>


    <td>
    <tr><td>I am nested in a table column </td><td>I am also nested in a table column  </td></tr>
    </td>


    <td>
    <tr><td>I am nested in the second table column </td><td>I am also nested the second table column  </td></tr>
    </td>


</tr>


</table>
```

But for some reason the browser renders it differently...

Can someone please help me so that the browser will render it just as shown on the HTML code i wrote? Thanks!

```
<table>

<tr>


    <td>
    <tr><td>I am nested in a table column </td><td>I am also nested in a table column  </td></tr>
    </td>


    <td>
    <tr><td>I am nested in the second table column </td><td>I am also nested the second table column  </td></tr>
    </td>


</tr>


</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td>I am nested in a table column</td>
        <td>I am also nested in a table column</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>I am nested in the second table column</td>
        <td>I am also nested the second table column</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chris97ong/xGsmz/1/).

Comment: Chris97ong. Thanks a lot for the response that works. I was trying to figure out on how to do this without nesting tables... But i guess this looks like the only solution! Thanks a lot!!!